# Static Class not being reference

Tags: c#, class, dll, static

I have a static class in a project which contains a couple of string constants.
Example:

```
 public static class ABC {
      public const string AC= "Account";
    }
```

Now I'm able to access that class from any solution in the project that the class is found but when I'm building the dll and referencing it in another project. I'm not able to access that class.

Comment: have you tried, cleaning your solution and rebuilding it.

Comment: What do you mean by *I'm not able to access that class.* ? What happens?

Comment: This code works fine. [See it yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pwgjc9).

Comment: when I try to use the contants like this: ABC.AC, i'm getting an error. It say there is no reference for that class but I do have another non-static class which is using the same namespace and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
namespace Test1
{
   public static class ABC
   {
     public const string AC = "Account";
   } 
}

using Test1;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Console.WriteLine( ABC.AC);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing but the ABC.AC is getting underlined. I cleaned the solution, build the dll again... nothing seems to work

Comment: Both your projects are under the same solution or different?

Comment: they are in different solution

Comment: Have you added the reference of dll file  in your executable project by right clicking  and select "Add Reference" option?